# Long wi-fi scanning time

Tags: android, wifi

I created an app that scans for access points and saves data about them (bssid and level of signal). Im using `WifiManager.startScan()` and `WifiManager.getScanResults()` methods.

Phone Im running my app on, is Sony Xperia Z2, with Android 6.0. App works fine, but times of each scan differs. It ranges from 4 seconds to even few minutes. It does not matter how many access points are in range.

My question is, why some scans takes so long? Is that matter of some kind of throttling? Is there way to "fix" it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly the answer you were looking for, but please keep in mind that Google has rigorously restricted the usage of `WifiManager.startScan` in newer Android versions. So no matter if the timing problems you are experiencing are related, maybe have a look into this to make sure you build a future-proof app.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan